# Divide a canvas into spaces of same width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I want to have a canvas which covers the full page (apart from a top area and a left area) as shown in the image below (blue area).

I want to divide the canvas in squares/rectangles (yellow lines) each one with the same height and width in a way that I can add some fixed size rectangle (green rectangles) in the grid. Well, something similar to Windows 7 Desktop grid (or Windows 8 Metro) in which icons are aligned to the grid.

The way I guessed to implement it is:

- draw the blue Canvas: get page height and width and subtract the grey area
- divide the Canvas in equal dimensions rectangles in a way that when I drag and drop one of the green rectangle into it gets aligned to the grid: no idea here
- drawing and dragging green rectangles (let's call them nodes): I'm going to use `appendTo()` to add a Div for each rectangle, and using jQuery UI to drag them. This is already done. Here is an example: http://myownlibrary.altervista.org/es4/
- One further step I would take is to make the canvas area extendable,that is, when all the rectangles contain some node, I want the canvas to "grow" in width/height (and it is going to be scrolled using horizontal and vertical scroll bars).

[image: it says canvas and has a grid]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Divide a canvas into spaces of same width and height

The first thing you need to determine is *how* you want to divide the space:

1. By a fixed number of columns and rows
2. By a predefined tile width and height.

For the latter you probably want to adjust the size to the closest, but to keep it simple lets stick to the first approach.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/q5j3Q/)

Lets say you want a fixed number of tiles:

```
var columns = 6,
    rows    = 4;
```

Then the size of each tile would be:

```
var tileWidth  = canvas.width / columns,
    tileHeight = canvas.height / rows;
```

This number may or may not be a float. If you need integer only values you simple round them:

```
var tileWidth  = Math.round(canvas.width / columns),
    tileHeight = Math.round(canvas.height / rows);
```

Now you can use indexes to determine the position for each tile:

```
var x = xIndex * tileWidth,
    y = yIndex * tileHeight;
```

This x and y can be used directly to set the position of a tile.

If you want to "snap" the tiles you need to use the mouse position relative to canvas:

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

    /// adjust mouse position to be relative to canvas
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        mx = e.clientX - rect.left,
        my = e.clientY - rect.top,

        /// get index from mouse position
        xIndex = Math.round(mx / tileWidth),
        yIndex = Math.round(my / tileHeight);

    /// calculate x and y based on previous formula
}
```

You may want to snap from the center of the tile and not the corner. Just subtract half the tile width and height from the mouse position to achieve that.

```
xIndex = Math.round((mx - tileWidth * 0.5) / tileWidth);
yIndex = Math.round((my - tileHeight * 0.5) / tileHeight);
```

You may want to check the index bounds (xIndex >= 0 && xIndex < columns etc.)

Comment: It's a good solution, but not for this problem. As your demo shows, the tiles do not end up "spaces of same width and height".